# Skip overlapping tick labels in Plotly Javascript

Tags: javascript, plotly, axis-labels

We are using scatter plots in Plotly.JS to display 2D graph data over a large X range, so we use logarithmic scaling. Zooming and panning works very well, except for one small issue: the X tick labels are confusing because Plotly uses single-digit labels for minor (non-powers of 10) ticks:

[image: default tick format]

I can use `tickFormat: '0.1s'` to show real numbers (which is what users want) instead of single digits, but then there are cases where these labels can overlap:

[image: format with 'tickformat: '0.1s'']

I can *also* add `dtick: 'D2'` which only displays subticks at positions 2 and 5 and not all digits, but this is then fixed and doesn't adjust to scaling any more.

Ideally, I could specify subtick-label digits where to skip the label (but not the vertical line) completely, *without* having to resort to `tickmode: array` and having to specify all tick labels manually, and still benefit from automatic tick adjustment depending on scaling.
For example, if all subtick digits are displayed, I would say I'd like to have tick labels at positions 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, the result would look like this:

[image: my preferred solution, but without specifying ticks manually]

The other display modes (digits 2 & 5 only, or just the power of 10) would not change.
Is there a way to do this? If so, how? I'm not afraid of patching Plotly if required, but right now I don't know where to start looking.

Comment: Usually I solve this by rotating the labels by some 35-45 degrees. That way they are all there and still readable.

Comment: You could write a function that allows you the specify the positions of the ticklabels. The function itself would use `tickmode: array`, but you'd only need to worry about coding the function once

Comment: @JohanFaerch, true, thank you, but after user feedback rotation is not optimal and they'd rather skip labels than having to tilt their heads for *every* label (even when there is sufficient space). :-)

Comment: @DerekO, we did this in the past, but this slowed down rendering significantly because on every rerender the subticks had to be recalculated. Also this function had some very weird race condition during resize & pan & zoom actions. Not too keen on going that road again ...

Comment: @Jens Fair enough  (pun intended ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I looked deeply into the Plotly configuration options and there are options that are semi-automatically modified 'live' depending on zoom levels, but the conditions **when** those modifications happen are hardcoded.

So here's a patch (for Plotly v1.36, because that's what we currently use). I modified some of the hardcoded conditions when to change from 1,10,100,... to 1,2,5,10,20,50,100,... to 1,2,3,4,5,... labeling on logarithmic axes and removed the tick labels at 4, 6, 8 and 9 for the last case to avoid text overlapping.

[image]

For my application, this now works well and I could not find any more overlapping of tick labels. Also, I got rid of the single digits between powers of ten which confused some users.

```
--- a/plotly-latest.v1.36.js    2021-05-24 21:45:28.000000000 +0100
+++ b/plotly-latest.v1.36.js    2022-02-02 10:21:08.000000000 +0100
@@ -127302,13 +127302,13 @@
         if(!nt) {
             if(ax.type === 'category') {
                 minPx = ax.tickfont ? (ax.tickfont.size || 12) * 1.2 : 15;
                 nt = ax._length / minPx;
             }
             else {
-                minPx = ax._id.charAt(0) === 'y' ? 40 : 80;
+                minPx = ax._id.charAt(0) === 'y' ? 40 : 100;
                 nt = Lib.constrain(ax._length / minPx, 4, 9) + 1;
             }
 
             // radial axes span half their domain,
             // multiply nticks value by two to get correct number of auto ticks.
             if(ax._name === 'radialaxis') nt *= 2;
@@ -127395,14 +127395,21 @@
     // Start with it cleared and mark that we're in calcTicks (ie calculating a
     // whole string of these so we should care what the previous date head was!)
     ax._prevDateHead = '';
     ax._inCalcTicks = true;
 
     var ticksOut = new Array(vals.length);
-    for(var i = 0; i < vals.length; i++) ticksOut[i] = axes.tickText(ax, vals[i]);
+    // if scaling == log, skip some intermediate tick labels to avoid overlapping text
+    var skipTexts = /^[4689]/;
+    var text;
+    for(var i = 0; i < vals.length; i++) {
+      text = axes.tickText(ax, vals[i]);
+      if(ax.type == "log" && ax.dtick == "D1" && text.text.match(skipTexts)) text.text = "";
+      ticksOut[i] = text;
+    }
     ax._inCalcTicks = false;
 
     return ticksOut;
 };
 
 function arrayTicks(ax) {
@@ -127535,18 +127542,20 @@
 
             // ticks on a linear scale, labeled fully
             roughDTick = Math.abs(Math.pow(10, rng[1]) -
                 Math.pow(10, rng[0])) / nt;
             base = getBase(10);
             ax.dtick = 'L' + roundDTick(roughDTick, base, roundBase10);
+            ax.tickformat = '';
         }
         else {
             // include intermediates between powers of 10,
             // labeled with small digits
             // ax.dtick = "D2" (show 2 and 5) or "D1" (show all digits)
-            ax.dtick = (roughDTick > 0.3) ? 'D2' : 'D1';
+            ax.dtick = (roughDTick > 0.4) ? 'D2' : 'D1';
+            ax.tickformat = '0.1s';
+            ax.hoverformat = '0.2s'; // Workaround to fix hoverinfo label formatting
         }
     }
     else if(ax.type === 'category') {
         ax.tick0 = 0;
         ax.dtick = Math.ceil(Math.max(roughDTick, 1));
     }
```

The patch is hereby released as Public Domain to make it as easy as possible to use this for direct integration into Plotly (maybe as a "D3" formatting option?).

Comment: Also submitted to Plotly.JS as a PR at https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/6105.

Answer (score 1):

Usually I solve this by rotating the labels by some 35-45 degrees. That way they are all there and still readable.

https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/#layout-xaxis-tickangle

```
tickangle
Parent: layout.xaxis
Type: angle
Default: "auto"

Sets the angle of the tick labels with respect to the horizontal. For example, a `tickangle` of -90 draws the tick labels vertically.
```

[image: Angled X labels]

Comment: If "tickangle = auto" would actually rotate only on demand, this would solve at least the overlapping issue. However, plotly.js already CAN decide how many ticks to display depending on available space (zoom level). Isn't there a location in the code to finetune this decision somewhere?